# Reading a pdf or word file using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pdf, plsql

Is there anyway to read a .pdf or .docx file using PL/SQL. I want to read a .pdf or .docx file stored in my hard disk and want to extract some information from the file. For example i have a file containing my name and email address and some other information in .pdf or .docx format i want to read the file and extract the name and email from it and store it into the database. In this case i know my name and email address but in reality i don't know the information.
Please anyone help me.

I read articles and i find CTX_DOC helpful but i don't know how to use this for my purpose.

*Note: All this using PL/SQL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Docx is zip archive. Extract it somewhere, get xml content and parse it with help of xmltype and XPath.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I did not understand why to do it and how ? @Dart

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/toc.htm) for this

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am a beginner can you help me further more? @materialdreams

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Well, I would start by exploring the documentation I have pointed you to.